# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not inserting or updating row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO wp_plugin_info (plugin_name,current_version,slug,download_link) 
VALUES ('.'"'.$name.'"'.','.$version.','.'"'.$slug.'"'.','.'"'.$link_download.'"'.') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
plugin_name = '.'"'.$name.'"'.', current_version = '.$version.', download_link = '.'"'.$link_download.'"'.'';
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

I am inserting plugin data into table on button click. But i want to check if plugin data already exist then don't insert it,  else insert it.

Here I assigned "slug" as UNIQUE key and "ID" is auto increment primary key.
I want to compare data based on slug.
Say for example if version changes .. then it must not insert new row in table.. Rather it will update row based on slug.

Here is my table :

```
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'plugin_info';

    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_name'") != $table_name) 
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `plugin_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `current_version` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `download_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY id (id),
    UNIQUE KEY `plugin_test` (`slug`)
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

Here is my code but it's  not working.

Comment: why don't you paste better the sql generated, instead of your code? it would be easier to help you (even for you to solve it by yourself...)

Comment: @JaimeDrq No, any unique index will work, it's not limited to the primary key. OP: if you say it does not work: *what* does happen instead? E.g. if it adds a new row instead of updating, your unique key does not work. If it e.g. does not do anything, it would indeed help if you add the actual query, as there could e.g. be unescaped data in your variables (e.g. for your varchar-field `version`, which you assume to be a number), resulting in an error (which you may or may not display).

Comment: It says : - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.3,"some slug","some link") ON DUPL' at line 1

Comment: Here is Query : - INSERT INTO wp_plugin_info (plugin_name,current_version,slug,download_link) VALUES ("some name",4.0.3,"some slug","some link") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE plugin_name = "some name", current_version = 4.0.3, download_link = "some link"

Comment: Okay I found my mistake .. I forgot to wrap '.$version.' with double quotes